# Can't post values of radio buttons using jQuery and php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the selected value of two radio buttons by posting via jQuery and processing it in PHP. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="purch" value="goods" checked>Goods<br>
<input type="radio" name="purch" value="services">Services
```

jQuery:

```
$("#addDoc").click(function(){
    $.post("manual.php",
    {
        invoice: $("#invoiceBox").val(),
        supplierName: $("#supplierBox").val(),
        refNo: $("#refBox").val(),
        vatReg: $("#vregBox").val(),
        vatPurch: $('input[name=purch]:checked', '#addForm').val()
    },
    function(data){
      alert(data);
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $vatPurch = $_POST['vatPurch'];

    echo $vatPurch;
?>
```

However I try to post it, I always get an 'Notice: Undefined index: vatPurch' error when submitting the form.

Comment: Can you print out the whole structure and see what it looks like?

Comment: `$_POST`. I suspect your values are getting saved (unless you're seeing errors in the JS console) but not in the way you expect.

Comment: Pull up your console, head to the Network tab, and check the request, is it even being sent? If sent, check what is being sent in the headers.

Comment: @ChristianTernus I tried printing the $_POST array but nothing comes up.

Comment: @tymeJV What console? How can I do that?

Comment: F12 typically brings it up, become VERY familiar with the console, it will save you countless hours debugging

Comment: The Javascript error console will allow you to see and debug errors like this. Here's how to open it in [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#opening_the_console), and [Safari](http://gardengnomesoftware.com/wiki/Using_The_Browser_Error_Console#Safari).

Comment: @tymeJV Thank you for pointing out the use of the console. As it turns out, the form is using the get method (the default, I suppose?) because I forgot to indicate the method on the form on the html code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 'vatPurch' instead of 'purch'

Give a try to this and (I hope) it will work

```
<?php
    $vatPurch = $_POST['purch'];
    echo $vatPurch;
?>
```